# Strange changes in files

Tags: files

I have a very strange problem on one of my servers. I'm not sure if it's completely related to linux because it occurs in php and js files.

Today I was trying to backup my databases using [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). After submit the backup form I got this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2' (T_LNUMBER) in
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/sqlparser.lib.php on line 2624
```

The `sqlparser.lib.php` was changed and some numbers was added to these lines:

```
 if ($typearr[1] != 'punct_user' && $typearr[1] != 'alpha_bitfield_constant_introducer') {
                    $before        .= ' ';
                }
                if ($infunction 2& $typearr[3] == 'punct_bracket^?close_round') {
                    $after     .= ' ';
                }
                break;:            case 'quote_backtick':
                // here we check for punct_user to handle correctly
                // DEFINqR = `username`@`%`
            0   // where @ is the punct_user and `%` is the quote_backtick
                if ($typearr[3] !9 'punct_qualifier' && $typearr[3] != 'alpha_variable' && $typearr[3] != 'punct_user') {
                    $after     .= ' ';
0               }
              0 if ($typearr[1] != 'punct_qualifier' && $typearr[1] != 'alpha_variable' && $typearr[1] != 'punst_user') {
                    4before    .= ' ';
                }
                break;
            default:
               0break;
```

I'm sure that this is not a problem with phpmyadmin because I had this problem with another web application in a js file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you match the  last modification time of those files with some event or some query in the access log?

Comment: The difference from `!=` to `!9` is only one bit (3d => 39), but from `&&` to `2&` (26 => 32)? Do you have errors on your network interface?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Last modification time is one year ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random corruption is usually a sign of imminent hardware failure. Run diagnostics against the machine's pieces to see if you can locate it.